# Django multi-criteria weighted rating

Tags: django, criteria, rating, weighted

I've started building an app in Django that will require multi-criteria weighted ratings. My issue is the exact same as [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?615350-Django-Multi-criteria-weighted-ratings) from a few years ago, which unfortunately did not have any answer.

If anybody out there can give me some hints on how to make multi-criteria weighted ratings in Django, I would love to hear about it! I'm pretty new to the whole Django/Python world and come from a PHP background.

Thanks a lot!

PS: I did not put too much info in this thread, because the problem is already described on the other topic [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?615350-Django-Multi-criteria-weighted-ratings). It's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for the weighted rating would be to add an additional field and populate it automatically in a [custom `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) on the rating object.

As far as getting the overall average rating goes, you can either calculate it dynamically every time it's needed (easiest/most accurate method) using [Django's aggregation queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), or you can try to maintain an average rating field that is updated each time a rating is added/deleted/updated (the more performant method if you're running a read-heavy service).  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956679/how-to-update-balance-in-a-accounting-app-with-django/11957666#11957666) for more details on implementing these (using sums rather than averages) and more detail on the tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. That's how I implemented it in PHP, with a cron task running regularly and calculating the weighted scores. The calculation on the go seems unrealistic in my case, as I am expecting several thousands of possible combinations. So I'll check this aggregation thing, but I might go for the other method. I was just wondering if there was some sort of a Django plugin or anything like this that could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a separate field that you need to maintain by overriding the save method, you need to follow this slightly more complex approach: [Using .aggregate() on a value introduced using .extra(select={...}) in a Django Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567543/using-aggregate-on-a-value-introduced-using-extraselect-in-a-django)

Comment: Thanks :) I don't think that it would be a real issue to add field.